# How to display data on label using stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, label

I am trying to display data using stored procedure on a label but I am not getting any output.

```
using(SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("service_profile", con);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlParameter sp_id1 = new SqlParameter("@sp_id",sp_id);
                SqlParameter rbx = new SqlParameter("@ReturnCode",rb);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(sp_id1);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(rbx);
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    Label2.Text = Convert.ToString(reader["sp_name"]);
                }
            }
```

Comment: 1. Are there any errors? 2. Is the stored proc returning any rows? 3. If you put a break to debug the code at the `reader.Read()`, can you see any rows?

Comment: To add to @WEI_DBA's comments above, do you have SET NOCOUNT ON in the stored procedure?

Comment: No it is not returning any rows.Can you tell if there is any other approach to display data on label using stored procedure

Comment: Can you run that stored procedure with the same parameters in `SSMS` and return results? Can you post the stored procedure?

Comment: There you go mate